# Как перечислить несколько элементов по id в js?

Tags: javascript, html

Надо обратиться ко всем параграфам (кроме последнего) через `id`, собрав все строки в одну переменную, и вывести это в последний параграф.

```
<p id="code1">Параграф №1</p> <!-- это -->
<p id="code2">Параграф №2</p> <!-- это -->
<p id="code3">Параграф №3</p> <!-- это -->
<p id="code4">Параграф №4</p> <!-- и это надо как то собрать в переменную -->
<p id="code5">Параграф №5</p> <!-- и вывести сюда -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу приучайте себя не писать кучу id с номерами. Для выборки по общему признаку используйте **классы**

```js
let allTexts = [...document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')].map(el => el.textContent);
document.querySelector('.output').textContent = allTexts.join(', ');
```

```html
<p class="my-class">Параграф №1</p>
<p class="my-class">Параграф №2</p>
<p class="my-class">Параграф №3</p>
<p class="my-class">Параграф №4</p>
<p class="output"><!-- вывести сюда --></p>
```

---

Здесь `.output` чисто для удобства. Он мог быть и id

---

Ко всем, кроме последнего:

```js
let allTexts = [...document.querySelectorAll('p.my-paragraph:not(:last-child)')].map(el => el.textContent);
document.querySelector('.output').textContent = allTexts.join(', ');
```

```html
<p class="my-paragraph">Параграф №1</p>
<p class="my-paragraph">Параграф №2</p>
<p class="my-paragraph">Параграф №3</p>
<p class="my-paragraph">Параграф №4</p>
<p class="my-paragraph output"><!-- вывести сюда --></p>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, помогли. Сам что-то вообще не подумал о классах:)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сменил последнему абзацу id на что-нибудь другое:

```js
document.getElementById('result').textContent = 
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="code"]')]
  .map(x => x.textContent)
  .join(" ")
```

```html
<p id="code1">Параграф №1</p>
<p id="code2">Параграф №2</p>
<p id="code3">Параграф №3</p>
<p id="code4">Параграф №4</p>
<p id="result">Параграф №5</p>
```

но если не менять, то можно так:

```js
document.getElementById('code5').textContent = 
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="code"]:not(#code5)')]
  .map(x => x.textContent)
  .join(" ")
```

```html
<p id="code1">Параграф №1</p>
<p id="code2">Параграф №2</p>
<p id="code3">Параграф №3</p>
<p id="code4">Параграф №4</p>
<p id="code5">Параграф №5</p>
```